# Find loop passing through two points with length $L\pi$

Tags: conic-sections, area, curves, arc-length

Problem: Find a nice simple closed curve other than circle which passes through the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ on the Cartesian plane and whose length is $L\pi$.

If the given condition is not the loop length but the loop area, it is easy to find a nice curve. The ellipse
$$(2x-1)^2+\frac{y^2}{4A^2}=1$$
has the area $A\pi .$

Can someone solve the problem above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, so $L$ has to be a parameter in the equation of the curve? I suspect that $L$ has to be $L \geq \frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Two segments $AC$ and $CB$ with lengths adding up to $L\pi$

Comment: Otherwise, an arc of circle. But that requires solving a transcedent equation.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca can you find the transendence equation?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca. It would be nice to have the equation. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I am more an idiot ga(R)y than an idiot question asker. Thanks for the intelligent jokes.

Answer (score 1):

If one desires to fit a circular arc cut from a circle of radius $r$ and azimuth $\alpha$ (in radians), the arc length is $$\alpha r=L\pi.$$
To have a nice symmetry one could place the circle center at $(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0=1/2$ (there may be other more asymmetric
solutions). The circle equation is $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$. To let the circle pass through $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$
we need $x_0^2+y_0^2=r^2$ and $(1-x_0)^2+y_0^2=r^2$, which requires $y_0=\pm \sqrt(r^2-x_0^2)$. The azimuth angle
is $\tan(\alpha/2)=x_0/|y_0|=x_0/\sqrt{r^2-x_0^2}$.
$$\alpha=2\arctan\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{r^2-x_0^2}}.$$
$$\alpha r=2r\arctan\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{r^2-x_0^2}}=L\pi.$$
and with $x_0=1/2$
$$2r\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{4r^2-1}}=L\pi.$$
This usually requires numerical solution. For small $L\pi-1$, therefore large $r$, one can get a first
estimate from the Taylor series,
$$2r\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{4r^2-1}}\approx 1+\frac{1}{24}\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{3}{640}\frac{1}{r^4}=L\pi,$$
which is a biquadratic equation in $r$.

Comment: Any idea for the ellipse ?

Comment: For the ellipse the full circumference is $aE(e)$, see Wikipedia. Setting half of this to $L\pi$, assuming the points of minmum and maximum $x$ run thru (0,0) and (1,0), requires inversion of an incomplete elliptic integral.

Comment: Are you using Mathematica notation for $E(e)$ ?What is $e$ (excentricity ?) Sorry for stupid questions ! Thanks & cheers.

Comment: $e$ is eccentricity. I'm using the standard notation where the argument $\pi/2$ for the angle is omitted. https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2 . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse . $a=1/2$, the semi-major axis in our case. Of course there is a typo above: this is the ''complete'' elliptic integral.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the simple answer, this is not an answer now!
Bu
$$(x-\tfrac12)^2+(y-\tfrac{\sqrt{L^2-1}}2)^2=\tfrac{L^2}4$$